# How to set Peer Address in SNMP4J library before sending traps?

Tags: snmp, snmp4j, snmp-trap

I am receiving traps from the device and want to forward it. Before forwarding I want to set peer address of the source system.

Answer (score 0):

Your SNMP manager could for example add the variable binding `snmpTrapAddress.0` to the trap, setting its value to the address of the originating host.

But this is a bit of a hack. If you're writing custom software just to forward traps, I'd suggest that you're reinventing the whell. Consider instead installing net-snmp and letting it forward the traps for you.